# Letting only one elasticsearch pod come up on a node in Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, rancher

We have a multi-node setup of our product where we need to deploy multiple Elasticsearch pods. As all these are data nodes and have volume mounts for persistent storage, we don't want to bring two pods up on the same node. I'm trying to use the anti-affinity feature of Kubernetes, but to no avail.

The cluster deployment is done through Rancher. We have 5 nodes in the cluster, and three nodes (let's say `node-1`, `node-2` `and node-3`) have the label `test.service.es-master: "true"`. So, when I deploy the helm chart and scale it up-to 3, Elasticsearch pods are up and running on all these three nodes. but if I scale it to 4, the 4th data node comes in one of the above mentioned nodes. Is that a correct behavior? My understanding was, imposing a strict anti-affinity should prevent the pods from coming up on the same node. I've referred to multiple blogs and forums (e.g. [this](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-taints-tolerations-affinities/) and [this](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/herding-pods-taints-tolerations-and-affinity-in-kubernetes-2279cef1f982)), and they suggest similar changes as mine. I'm attaching the relevant section of the helm chart.

The requirement is, we need to bring up ES on only those nodes which are labelled with specific key-value pair as mentioned above, and each of those nodes should only contain one pod. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  ...
  selector:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test.service.es-master: "true"
  serviceName: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  affinity:
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: test.service.es-master
            operator: In
            values:
            - "true"
        topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        test.service.es-master: "true"
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: test.service.es-master
                operator: In
                values:
                  - "true"
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      securityContext:
             ...
      volumes:
        ...
      ...
status: {}
```

**Update-1**

As per the suggestions in the comments and answers, I've added the anti-affinity section in template.spec. But unfortunately the issue still remains. The updated yaml looks like as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  namespace: default
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: {{ .Values.service.httpport | quote }}
    port: {{ .Values.service.httpport }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.httpport }}
  - name: {{ .Values.service.tcpport | quote }}
    port: {{ .Values.service.tcpport }}
    targetPort: {{ .Values.service.tcpport }}
  selector:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    test.service.es-master: "true"
  name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test.service.es-master: "true"
  serviceName: {{ .Values.service.name }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        test.service.es-master: "true"
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: test.service.es-master
              operator: In
              values:
              - "true"
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: test.service.es-master
                operator: In
                values:
                  - "true"
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
      securityContext:
             readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      volumes:
       - name: elasticsearch-data-volume
         hostPath:
            path: /opt/ca/elasticsearch/data
      initContainers:
         - name: elasticsearch-data-volume
           image: busybox
           securityContext:
                  privileged: true
           command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1010:1010 /var/data/elasticsearch/nodes"]
           volumeMounts:
              - name: elasticsearch-data-volume
                mountPath: /var/data/elasticsearch/nodes
      containers:
      - env:
        {{- range $key, $val := .Values.data }}
        - name: {{ $key }} 
          value: {{ $val | quote }}
        {{- end}}
        image: {{ .Values.image.registry }}/analytics/{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}
        name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
        ports:
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.httpport }}
        - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.tcpport }}
        volumeMounts:
              - name: elasticsearch-data-volume
                mountPath: /var/data/elasticsearch/nodes    
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}
          requests:
            memory: {{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}
        restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

Comment: I believe you should put `podAntiAffinity` into `template.spec` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue. :(

Comment: What version of Kubernetes is your cluster?

Comment: It's Kubernetes 1.11.5

Comment: Can you try changing `apiVersion` for your deployment to `apiVersion: apps/v1` instead of `apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1`?

Comment: No luck, even with this change.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide 100% correctly formatted and spaced yaml? Or perhaps provide it as JSON?

Comment: I've updated the yaml. Please note, it refers to a `values.yaml` which I can't share publicly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, both in your initial manifest and even in the updated manifest you are using `topologyKey` for `nodeAffinity` which will give you an error while trying to deploy those manifest using `kubectl create` or `kubectl apply` because there is no api key called `topologyKey` for `nodeAffinity` Ref [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/federation/extensions/v1beta1/definitions/#_v1_nodeselectorterm)

Secondly, you are using a key called `test.service.es-master` for your nodeAffinity are you sure your "node" has those labels? please confirm by this command `kubectl get nodes --show-labels`

Lastly, Augmenting to [@Laszlo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262629/laszlo-valko) answer and your [@bitswazsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4245859/bitswazsky) comment on it to simplify it, you can use the below code:

Here I have used a node label (as key) called `role` to identify the node, you can add that to your existing clusters' node by executing this command `kubectl label nodes <node-name> role=platform`

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: role
                operator: In
                values:
                - platform
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: component
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Answer (score 4):

As Egor suggested, you need podAntiAffinity:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-cache
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: store
  replicas: 3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: store
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - store
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Source: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#always-co-located-in-the-same-node

So, with your current label, it might look like this:

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
    # node affinity stuff here
    podAntiAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - labelSelector:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: "test.service.es-master"
            operator: In
            values:
            - "true"
        topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
```

Ensure that you put this in the correct place in your yaml, or else it won't work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I've updated my question with the changes you suggested. But unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with Kubernetes 1.11.5:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      test.service.es-master: "true"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        test.service.es-master: "true"
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: test.service.es-master
                operator: In
                values:
                - "true"
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: test.service.es-master
                operator: In
                values:
                  - "true"
      containers:
      - image: nginx:1.7.10
        name: nginx
```

I don't know why you chose the same key/value for the pod deployment selector label, as for the node selector. They are confusing as a minimum...

Comment: Hi, the reason for choosing same k/v pair was to ensure that only one ES pod comes up on each node, and they only come up on those nodes, which are labelled accordingly. If you have any less confusing (and more elegant) way of achieving the same functionality, please feel free to add it to the answer :)